# Build argument in docker compose not evaluated correctly

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, docker-compose

I have a `Dockerfile` containing

```
ARG GROUP_ID=1000
RUN groupadd -g $GROUP_ID foo
```

and a `compose.yaml` file with a container declared as

```yaml
services:
  bar:
    build:
      args:
        GROUP_ID: "$(id -g)"
```

Running `docker compose build bar` fails with

```
groupadd: invalid group ID '$(id'
```

Why is it not using the whole `$(id -g)` and evaluating it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside docker compose yaml you cannot invoke shell commands by `$( ...command... )`.

You have to apply the following approach (which I used many times):

**docker compose yaml**

```yaml
services:
  bar:
    build:
      args:
        GROUP_ID: "${MY_GROUP_ID}"
```

**build script**

```bash
MY_GROUP_ID=$(id -g)

MY_GROUP_ID=${MY_GROUP_ID} docker-compose build ...some_arguments...
```