# Why are docker compose variables not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker compose override file, which I am using exclusively for testing:

```
---
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    image: "dolthub/dolt-sql-server"
    volumes:
      - "nautobot_data:/var/lib/dolt"
    env_file:
      - "local.env"
    command: ["-u ${MYSQL_USER}", "-p ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"]
    restart: "unless-stopped"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
volumes:
  nautobot_data:
```

I have the following contents in the `local.env` file:

```
MYSQL_USER=nautobot
MYSQL_PASSWORD=<removed for privacy>
```

When I run `docker compose -f docker-compose.override.yml config` I see the following in the output:

```
name: nautobot-docker-compose
services:
  db:
    command:
    - '-u '
    - '-p '
    environment:
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: <removed for privacy>
      MYSQL_USER: nautobot
      ...
    image: dolthub/dolt-sql-server
    networks:
      default: null
    ports:
    - mode: ingress
      target: 3306
      published: "3306"
      protocol: tcp
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: nautobot_data
      target: /var/lib/dolt
      volume: {}
networks:
  default:
    name: nautobot-docker-compose_default
volumes:
  nautobot_data:
    name: nautobot-docker-compose_nautobot_data
```

When I run `docker compose -f docker-compose.override.yml up` I see the following in the output:

```
WARN[0000] The "MYSQL_USER" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "MYSQL_PASSWORD" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

If I run `docker ps --no-trunc` I see the following in the output:

```
CONTAINER ID                                                       IMAGE                     COMMAND                                      CREATED          STATUS         PORTS                               NAMES
4db42b166f1dd478c00bfbdca68507f8a18a4c05c904841776b3c3b66ac92f9c   dolthub/dolt-sql-server   "tini -- docker-entrypoint.sh '-u ' '-p '"   10 minutes ago   Up 9 seconds   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   nautobot-docker-compose-db-1
```

I've also tried single quotes: `command: ['-u ${MYSQL_USER}', '-p ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}']`

**Why are the `MYSQL_USER` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD` variables not being applied?**

Comment: Seems I have a misunderstanding of the variables and found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64723235/docker-compose-environment-variables-blank-string Problem is solved by adding `--env-file local.env` to the docker compose command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build argument in docker compose not evaluated correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76668316/build-argument-in-docker-compose-not-evaluated-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Compose has two layers of environment variables.  When the Compose file includes variable references like `${MYSQL_USER}`, those come from the host's environment, specifically a `.env` file, or a [`docker-compose --env-file` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#substitute-with---env-file).  The container gets its own separate environment, provided by `env:` and `env_file:`.

That is: Compose evaluates `command:` using the host's environment, and this happens separately from using `env_file:` to specify the container's environment.

It should work to explicitly specify the alternate environment file:

```sh
docker compose \
  -f docker-compose.override.yml \
  --env-file local.env \
  config
```

Your `command:` is not a shell command.  (Beware the extra spaces embedded in between `-u` and the user name in the individual options.)  If it were, you can ask Compose to run a shell to interpret the container command, being careful to double the `$` characters so Compose doesn't interpret them itself.  In this case the parameter expansion would happen in the shell, inside the container, which would get to see the `env_file:` values.

```yaml
command:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - >
      dolt_server -u "$$MYSQL_USER" -p "$$MYSQL_PASSWORD""
```